# Fatal error: Call to a member function modify() on a non-object

Tags: php

My PHP code is:

```
require_once("config.inc.php");
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');

$username = "Michael";
$result = $conn->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM gebruikers, afdelingen
    WHERE gebruikers.afdeling_id = afdelingen.afdeling_id 
    AND gebruikersnaam = '".$username."'
");

$value = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
$allow_times1 = $value->allow_time;
echo $allow_times1; // output: 09:00,14:00,17:20,21:00

$allow_times2 = "09:00,14:00,17:20,21:00";
echo $allow_times2; // output: 09:00,14:00,17:20,21:00

$myArray = explode(',', $allow_times1);
foreach($myArray as $my_Array) {
    $timeFrom = "$my_Array:00";
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $timeFrom)->modify("+5 minutes");
}
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function modify() on a non-object in
>   /srv/websites/kabouter/htdocs/test/test.php on line 30

I won't get the error if I change:

```
$myArray = explode(',', $allow_times1);
```

to:

```
$myArray = explode(',', $allow_times2);
```

Why do I get the error with $allow_times1, while $allow_times1 and $allow_times2 has the same echo-output? All helps are welcome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that explode is on line 30?

Comment: Maybe try to explicitely cast `$value->allow_time` to string: `$allow_times1 = (string) $value->allow_time;`

Comment: Why are you doing `$timeFrom = "$my_Array:00";` when you could just amend the format in `createFromFormat('H:i', $timeFrom)->modify("+5 minutes");`

Comment: Try removing the method chaining.and then add a `DateTime::getLastErrors()` after the `DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $timeFrom)` as per [the manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.getlasterrors.php) as its obviously the `createFromFormat()` that is failing for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I think `$allow_times1` is a object, not a string ,when you call `echo $allow_times1` , then it turns to call the `__toString()` method of $allow_times1 object

Comment: I doubt it. Its a column from a table and he echo's it

Answer (score 0):

I finally find out how to fix the problem.

PHP Code Solution:

```
$allow_times1 = substr($allow_times1, 0, -1);
```

With the code above it will fix the problem....
It is strange that $allow_times1 added a "space" ...